# Higher resolution with hexsticker hexagon logo in R?

Tags: r, hexsticker

We can see [examples of how to make a hexagon sticker](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/hexSticker).

The one with the cat on it is a good example of a hex sticker with an image.

i.e.

```
imgurl <- system.file("figures/cat.png", package="hexSticker")
sticker(imgurl, package="hexSticker", p_size=20, s_x=1, s_y=.75, s_width=.6,
        filename="inst/figures/imgfile.png")
```

I have a high resolution png, which looks very nice on its own, but when I put it into the hexsticker, it looses resolution (badly).

I am not so experienced with hexsticker (nor with its graphics/ggplot internals), so am not sure how to force the resulting graphic to be of a higher resolution (or if it's possible to generate it in vector?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's easy, just use the `dpi` argument, like so

```
sticker(imgurl, package="hexSticker", p_size=20, s_x=1, s_y=.75, s_width=.6,
        filename="inst/figures/imgfile.png",

        dpi = 1000 # higher dpi means higher resolution

        )
```